Appium Server is freezing when installing my app on real android device
I'm trying to start app test automation using my MacBook with Appium server and Appium inspector. I use real android (Xiaomi) devise connected with USB cable. When I start session in  Appium inspector with listed bellow capabilities I expect app is getting installed, but the  server is freezing on the step:
[ADB] Running '/.../Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P 5037 -s 'devise_id' shell dumpsys deviceidle whitelist +io.appium.settings ; dumpsys deviceidle whitelist +io.appium.uiautomator2.server ; dumpsys deviceidle whitelist +io.appium.uiautomator2.server.test ;'

In Appium inspector I see timeout error
Here is my capabilities
{
  "appium:automationName": "UiAutomator2",
  "appium:platformName": "Android",
  "appium:platformVersion": "13",
  "appium:deviceName": "6c2a695b",
  "appium:app": "/...path.../app_name.apk"

So I'm wondering what could be the problem?

I reinstalled Appium server
I reinstalled Android sdk tools
I tried with different (including test samples) apps
I tried with 2 different real android devices and 1 emulator

